# Limpar string em Python (remover caracteres de escape)

Tags: python

Me deparei com algumas strings com o seguinte conteúdo, exemplo:

`"++++++//texto+++!!!+++//texto++++"`

estou tentando encontrar um método de limpar a frase mas não estou obtendo sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O que quer dizer "limpar a frase"? Como seria o resultado esperado/desejado neste caso?

Comment: quis dizer remover os caracteres como esses "+, /" no meio da string, acredito que posso fazer isso usando expressões regulares, mas estou perdido em como fazer.

Comment: Se são poucos caracteres a serem removidos, você pode usar o `minha_string.replace('+', '')`, por exemplo. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: Infelizmente são mais caracteres, eu precisava de uma forma que meio que desse uma formatada no texto, vou te explicar melhor o que estou fazendo, estou usando scrapy para extrair dados de uma pagina e a descrição de alguns itens vem desta forma que citei, queria a descrição em um bom formato para adicionar a lista dos itens extraídos. Por Exemplo, se o texto vem: "++++//jamanta+++de+++//pedra++++" ele guardasse "jamanta de pedra".

Comment: O titulo da sua pergunta não está 100% correto, o que vc quer remover não, necessariamente, "caracteres de escape".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar Regex(Expressões regulares) para achar tais palavras, segue um pequeno exemplo:

```
import re

test1 = "31teste123 regex==="
test2 = "++++//jamanta+++de+++//pedra++++"

def formatString(string):
    formatedArray = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', string)
    print(" ".join(formatedArray))

formatString(test1)
formatString(test2)
```

O output seria um array contendo as palavras:

test1 = ['teste', 'regex']

test2 = ['jamanta', 'de', 'pedra']

Você pode testar mais coisas neste site: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Para imprimir da forma que ele quer, é possível fazer desta maneira: `print(" ".join(formatedArray))`, o resultado é cada palavra separada por um espaço

Comment: Fica dando NameError: name 'formatedArray' is not defined. Desculpa se a perguntar for besta...

Comment: @MiltonTeixeira Aqui está rodando normalmente, tente adicionar esta linha: formatedArray = ""

Comment: @MiltonTeixeira Adicione ela antes de usar o formatedArray

Comment: s = '+++++texto++++texto+++++'

formatedArray = "" –

s = s.replace("+", "")
print (s.join(formatedArray))

Comment: assim? cara desculpa eu to tentando aprender isso.

Comment: @MiltonTeixeira não, você está misturando as duas soluções, o meu código por si só já retira todos os caracteres, como esse "+", faça como eu fiz, utilize uma função.

Comment: vinicius quanto tento printar o teu código ele retorna None... acredito que estou fazendo algo errado.

Comment: aliás perdão ele retorna exatamente como você disse, mas eu preciso que retorne "Jamanta de pedra"

Comment: @MiltonTeixeira Foi editado o código, teste agora.

Comment: Poxa Vinicius muito obrigado, te devo umas cevas!